# i3wm floating windows (new issue)

Tags: config, i3

I am not even sure this is possible, but I am curious because it would be useful.

I have the default i3 binding `mod+enter` which opens my terminal.
What I would like to do is create a binding that will open a terminal that is floating.

In other words, I need to execute terminator 2 different ways, standard and floating. I have been through the docs and have looked at many different configs, but I can't find anyone doing this (and I can't quite figure it out myself).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add something like this to your `~/.i3/config` (or `~/.config/i3/config`):

```
bindsym Mod+Shift+Enter exec terminator --role=floating
for_window [window_role="^floating$"] floating enable
```

The first line binds the key combination <kbd>Mod</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to start `termite` with the `WM_WINDOW_ROLE` property set to "floating". By default `WM_WINDOW_ROLE` is not set by `terminator`, so this can be used as criterion to differentiate between normal and floating windows.
The second line will tell *i3* to enable floating mode on any window that has `WM_WINDOW_ROLE` set to (exactly) "floating".

---

This works also the same for some (all?) other *vte3* based terminals, like `gnome-terminal` or `termite`. Other tools might provide similar command line options to change the role.

Sometimes the WM_CLASS can also be changed. In that case `class` would have to be used instead of `window_role` in the *i3* configuration.

Comment: Nice. Did not consider a `role` flag. Thank you.